# keydown not firing on Enter key using button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, keydown

I am creating a winforms application and I am simply trying to use a button to allow the user to submit the form. I have the following code for the button

```
With duplicate_button
    .Parent = action_box
    .TabIndex = 4
    .Width = 125
    .Top = 25
    .Left = (.Parent.Width / 2) - (.Width / 2)
    AddHandler .KeyDown, AddressOf duplicate
End With

Private Sub duplicate(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
     Console.Write(e.KeyCode)
End Sub
```

However, the duplicate function does not get called when the user presses the enter key. It does get called for any other key on the keyboard, just not the enter key. But I really only need it to work for the enter key.

I already tried setting the previewkeys to true and setting the acceptbutton on the form to this button, but neither of them changed anything.

I also tried using the keypress event, but again the enter key is not detected.

Comment: So, the code that doesnt work is not the code you posted?

Comment: Use the form's `KeyDown` event instead (which is what the `KeyPreview` property affects). The button's `KeyDown` event is only raised if the button has focus when you press a key.

Comment: @Plutonix the code that doesn't work is the firing of the keydown event which the addhandler line is supposed to create. So the code that doesn't work is posted. If the function "duplicate" doesn't even get called how could it be the culprit?

Comment: @Visual Vincent, that is the objective. I only want the event to fire when the button has focus.

Comment: Okay, what do you want to happen when the user presses ENTER then? Can you show us the `duplicate` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a Button has the Focus, pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key will raise the `Click` and `KeyUp` events.

The <kbd>TAB</kbd> Key will raise the KeyUp event, if pressing that Key will cause the Focus to reach the Button, but not if it's pressed to move the Focus to another control.
If <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> are pressed to move the Focus to the `Button`, the `KeyUp` event is raised twice.
The `KeyDown` event is raised only when pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> keys to move the Focus to the previous control in the `TabIndex` order.

Any other key pressed while the Button has the Focus, will raise the `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events.

The `KeyPreview` property of the Form will not change this behavior.
With the exception of the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> keys, when used to move the Focus to the previous control.
In this case, only the `KeyDown` event is raised.

If the Button is the [AcceptButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [CancelButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) of a Form, pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> keys will raise the `Click` event of the Button.
This could cause a problem if multiline `TextBox` controls are also present, because pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key will not generate a new line, since the `KeyDown` event is not raised for this Key, only `KeyUp`.